# Flutter Bloc Testing not catching thenThrow WebException

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, bloc, webexception

I'm trying to test the BLoCs in my Flutter App but I hit a wall with this problem below.

```
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                                 _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart                       runBlocTest.<fn>
dart:async                                                 runZoned
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 157:9                 runBlocTest
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 127:11                blocTest.<fn>

Expected: [
            ChangePasswordLoading:ChangePasswordLoading,
            ChangePasswordFailure:ChangePasswordFailure
          ]
  Actual: [
            ChangePasswordLoading:ChangePasswordLoading,
            ChangePasswordSuccess:ChangePasswordSuccess
          ]
   Which: at location [1] is ChangePasswordSuccess:<ChangePasswordSuccess> instead of ChangePasswordFailure:<ChangePasswordFailure>

package:test_api                             expect
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 176:9   runBlocTest.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                   _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart         runBlocTest.<fn>
dart:async                                   runZoned
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 157:9   runBlocTest
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 127:11  blocTest.<fn>
```

which is caused by this Failing BLoC test

```
blocTest<ChangePasswordBloc, ChangePasswordState>(
      'emits [ChangePasswordLoading, ChangePasswordFailure] on failed ChangePassword',
      build: () {
        when(authenticationRepository.changePassword(
          'token',
          'oldPassword',
          'newPassword',
          'newPasswordConfirm',
        )).thenThrow(WebException(403));
        return changePasswordBloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc
        ..add(ChangePassword(
          oldPassword: 'oldPassword',
          newPassword: 'newPassword',
          newPasswordConfirm: 'newPasswordConfirm',
        )),
      expect: [
        ChangePasswordLoading(),
        ChangePasswordFailure(error: 'Old password is not correct'),
      ],
      errors: [isA<WebException>()],
    );
```

This is the code I have used to test my ChangePasswordBloc (Notice all the other tests are passing successfully)

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/business_logic/blocs/change_password/change_password_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/business_logic/blocs/change_password/change_password_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/business_logic/blocs/change_password/change_password_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/data/exceptions/web_exception.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/data/repositories/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockAuthenticationRepository extends Mock
    implements AuthenticationRepository {}

class MockSecureStorage extends Mock implements FlutterSecureStorage {}

main() {
  ChangePasswordBloc changePasswordBloc;
  MockSecureStorage secureStorage;
  MockAuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository;

  setUp(() {
    secureStorage = MockSecureStorage();
    authenticationRepository = MockAuthenticationRepository();
    changePasswordBloc = ChangePasswordBloc(
      authenticationRepository,
      secureStorage,
    );
  });

  tearDown(() {
    changePasswordBloc?.close();
  });

  test(
    'initial state is ChangePasswordInitial',
    () => expect(changePasswordBloc.state, ChangePasswordInitial()),
  );

  group('ChangePassword process', () {
    blocTest<ChangePasswordBloc, ChangePasswordState>(
      'emits [ChangePasswordLoading, ChangePasswordSuccess] on successful ChangePassword',
      build: () {
        when(authenticationRepository.changePassword(
          'token',
          'oldPassword',
          'newPassword',
          'newPasswordConfirm',
        )).thenAnswer((_) async => null);
        return changePasswordBloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc
        ..add(ChangePassword(
          oldPassword: 'oldPassword',
          newPassword: 'newPassword',
          newPasswordConfirm: 'newPasswordConfirm',
        )),
      expect: [
        ChangePasswordLoading(),
        ChangePasswordSuccess(),
      ],
    );

    blocTest<ChangePasswordBloc, ChangePasswordState>(
      'emits [ChangePasswordLoading, ChangePasswordFailure] on failed ChangePassword',
      build: () {
        when(authenticationRepository.changePassword(
          'token',
          'oldPassword',
          'newPassword',
          'newPasswordConfirm',
        )).thenThrow(WebException(403));
        return changePasswordBloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc
        ..add(ChangePassword(
          oldPassword: 'oldPassword',
          newPassword: 'newPassword',
          newPasswordConfirm: 'newPasswordConfirm',
        )),
      expect: [
        ChangePasswordLoading(),
        ChangePasswordFailure(error: 'Old password is not correct'),
      ],
      errors: [isA<WebException>()],
    );
  });
}
```

This is my ChangePasswordBloc code

**ChangePasswordBloc**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_app/data/exceptions/web_exception.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/data/repositories/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'change_password_event.dart';
import 'change_password_state.dart';

class ChangePasswordBloc
    extends Bloc<ChangePasswordEvent, ChangePasswordState> {
  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  final FlutterSecureStorage _secureStorage;

  ChangePasswordBloc(AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
      FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage)
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        _secureStorage = secureStorage,
        super(ChangePasswordInitial());

  @override
  Stream<ChangePasswordState> mapEventToState(
    ChangePasswordEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is ChangePassword) {
      yield* _mapChangePasswordToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<ChangePasswordState> _mapChangePasswordToState(
      ChangePassword event) async* {
    yield ChangePasswordLoading();
    try {
      final accessToken = await _secureStorage.read(key: 'accessToken');

      await _authenticationRepository.changePassword(
        accessToken,
        event.oldPassword,
        event.newPassword,
        event.newPasswordConfirm,
      );
      yield ChangePasswordSuccess();
    } on WebException catch (e) {
      String errorMessage;
      if (e.statusCode == 422) {
        errorMessage = 'Password must be 8 characters long';
      } else if (e.statusCode == 419) {
        errorMessage = 'New Password is not matching';
      } else if (e.statusCode == 403) {
        errorMessage = 'Old password is not correct';
      }
      yield ChangePasswordFailure(error: errorMessage ?? e.toString());
    } catch (err) {
      yield ChangePasswordFailure(
          error: err.toString() ?? 'An unknown error occurred');
    }
  }
}
```

As you can tell, if a WebException is thrown, I yield ChangePasswordFailure() with an error message. This does work on the actual app, so I am certain that logic works, yet the test does not seem to catch that thrown WebException.

**ChangePasswordEvent**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

abstract class ChangePasswordEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ChangePassword extends ChangePasswordEvent {
  final String oldPassword;
  final String newPassword;
  final String newPasswordConfirm;

  ChangePassword({
    @required this.oldPassword,
    @required this.newPassword,
    @required this.newPasswordConfirm,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [oldPassword, newPassword, newPasswordConfirm];
}
```

**ChangePasswordState**

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class ChangePasswordState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ChangePasswordInitial extends ChangePasswordState {}

class ChangePasswordLoading extends ChangePasswordState {}

class ChangePasswordSuccess extends ChangePasswordState {}

class ChangePasswordFailure extends ChangePasswordState {
  final String error;

  ChangePasswordFailure({@required this.error});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}
```

Any suggestions or advice as to why .thenThrow(WebException(403)) is not actually being caught when it actually works on the real Flutter App (if a WebException is thrown, ChangePasswordFailure is always thrown)?

I have another example with the *same* code which does work (The code for ClientInfoBloc is handles WebExceptions in the same way as ChangePasswordBloc and it also works in the real Flutter app)

[Working Test Example with thrown WebException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CztnY.png)

I checked this related [issue](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1145) but it did not fix anything.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add another 'when' block to mock this line:
`final accessToken = await _secureStorage.read(key: 'accessToken');`
something like this:
`when(secureStorage.read(key: 'accessToken')).thenAnswer(() async => 'token');`
or remove the parameter 'token' of your current 'when' block.
Because you are currently saying that when you call the 'changePassword' method with the attribute accessToken = 'token' it will throw an error and that is not true because accessToken = null.